# How to get from points array points with biggest Y and smallest Y?

Tags: c#, .net

I have points Array Points[].
How can I get from this array points with biggest Y and smallest Y.
Thank in advance.

Comment: You have 2 conditions. So: AND or OR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Point Max = Points.MaxBy(p => p.Y);
Point Min = Points.MinBy(p => p.Y);
```

This is using [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Comment: Max an Min could have to be collections in this case. It's not clear.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True, but if he just wants them like that `OrderBy(Descending)` will work wonders.

Answer (score 2):

```
var maxY= array.Max(x=>x.Y);
var minY= array.Min(x=>x.Y);
Point maxPoint = array.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Y == maxY);
Point minPoint = array.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Y == minY);
```

Comment: if **OP wants all points with the highest/lowest Y-value** then nothing do, all points are should return :)

Comment: Consider these 6 points: `{ new Point(100, 100), new Point(50, 100), new Point(10, 250), new Point(10, 1000), new Point(50, 100), new Point(100, 1000) }`. I count two points in min-y: `100,100` and `50,100` and two points as max-y: `10,1000` and `100,1000`. You would show only one arbitrary point for min and max.

Comment: @TimSchmelter check the accepted answer,  it is all about unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with Linq:

```
var pointYGroups = points.GroupBy(p => p.Y).OrderBy(g => g.Key);
IEnumerable<Point> smallessY_Points = pointYGroups.First();
IEnumerable<Point> largestY_Points = pointYGroups.Last();

// output
foreach (var minPoint in smallessY_Points)
    Console.WriteLine("Point: [{0}|{1}]", minPoint.X, minPoint.Y);
```

Comment: He wants the `Point` object related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point[] a = new Point[]{

            new Point() { X = 0, Y = 3 },
            new Point() { X = 1, Y = 3 },
            new Point() { X = 2, Y = 1 },
            new Point() { X = 3, Y = 1 },
            new Point() { X = 1, Y = 2 }
        };
        var max = a.Max(p1 => p1.Y);
        var min = a.Min(p1 => p1.Y);
        var maxY = a.Where(p => p.Y == max).ToArray();
        var minY = a.Where(p => p.Y == min).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, no no. This can turn out to be something like `O(2(n^2))`... Move the #max/Min out of the FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Thanks, updated. Still, are you sure that keeping the max/min inside the `Where` (which produces an `IEnumerable`), would produce an evaluation on each `==` checking?

Comment: It would, yes, as it's a selector function.

Comment: You are right, thanks again for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Array.lenth(),and add an element,to get the biggest or smallest.But if you want improve the ability of algorithm,you must learn how the Array deal with the numbers.